# What is TeXdoctk? Is it safe to Remove? How do I remove it?

Tags: gnome, package-management, uninstall, 17.10, installed-programs

As the title implies, whilst using Ubuntu 17.10 I have come across a program called TeXdoctk in the Gnome menu. I cannot work out what its purpose is and attempting to uninstall it via:

```
sudo apt purge texdoctk
```

Has had no effect...

So what exactly is it? Is it safe to remove? And if so, how?

Comment: It is provided by the texlive-base package. See also https://bugs.debian.org/836441 for background and the process to remove texdoctk from texlive-base.

Comment: Do you have GNOME Builder installed?

Comment: @Tooniis no I do not have GNOME Builder installed

Comment: For me it appeared after I installed Builder, so I thought it was a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

> > So what exactly is it?

**TeXdoctk is a [TeX](https://tug.org/) documentation browser**

[TeX is a system for typesetting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)  For example it's used for some of the Debian manuals.

[image]

TeXdoctk is clearly old and klunky, but so far I haven't found anything better for **TeX**.

This description below could I think be said more simply as **"Use a menu to display TeX help"**.

---

[image]

**Also,** seems some of the stuff in them menu is not loaded, in other words the menu is created NOT from your system, but globally somewhere, and your system may, or may not, have that documentation loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, it is a GUI that comes along with `texlive`, which is the package for using TeX. If you don't use TeX then
you can type in the command below to uninstall it

```
sudo apt remove texlive-base
```

Comment: Your answer is half-baked, tell OP if the app is safe to remove in addition to your answer and your good to go!

Comment: Yes please, I would like to know if its safe to remove, like would it have any negative impact on my system if I removed it?

Comment: @AdLinux if you need to use latex then removing texlive-base will leave you unable to do so